# SQLiteDataAdapter Update not updating

Tags: c#, sqlite, sqldataadapter, dataadapter

```
    private void potrdi_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {    
        string id = idFilma.Text;
        double nova = double.Parse(novaOcena.Text);

        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        string povNiz = @"Data Source=C:\Users\filmi.sqlite;Version=3";
        SQLiteConnection povezava = new SQLiteConnection(povNiz);

        SQLiteDataAdapter dataAdapter = new SQLiteDataAdapter("SELECT id, naslov, ocena FROM filmi WHERE id =" + id, povezava);
        dataAdapter.Fill(ds);

        SQLiteCommand cmd = new SQLiteCommand("UPDATE filmi SET ocena = " + nova + " WHERE id = " + id, povezava);

        SQLiteCommandBuilder builder = new SQLiteCommandBuilder(dataAdapter);
        dataAdapter.UpdateCommand = builder.GetUpdateCommand(true);

        dataAdapter.UpdateCommand = cmd;
        dataAdapter.Update(ds);

        prikazPodatkov2.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
    }
```

I've been working in Windows Form Application.

The update after select just isn't working. I tried many things but none of them worked for me. I'm using sqlite database. After update I get the same results as in the select before update.

Please help I've been trying to fix this for three days already and it's driving me nuts.

Answer (score 0):

use `dataAdapter.AcceptChangesDuringUpdate = true;` before `dataAdapter.Update(ds);`

```
...
SQLiteCommandBuilder builder = new SQLiteCommandBuilder(dataAdapter);
dataAdapter.UpdateCommand = builder.GetUpdateCommand(true);

dataAdapter.UpdateCommand = cmd;
dataAdapter.AcceptChangesDuringUpdate = true;
dataAdapter.Update(ds);
...
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for the reply; I tried adding the suggested line before the Update but it still doesn't work.